# How to load a CSV file located on the local server into MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to upload data from a CSV file located on the local server where MySQL is hosted. So I tried using the "Data Load" command in mysql but I get the following fatal error

```
MySQL Database Error: Fatal error encountered during command execution
```

This is this my query

```
TRUNCATE TABLE setup_new_campaign;
LOAD DATA LOCAL infile 'D:\\Uploads\setup_new_campaign.csv'
into table setup_new_campaign
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

The hosted server is a Windows.

Comment: Are you sure that the line endings in the csv file is windows style ie `\r\n` and not `\n` and how to you try to load the file, from the terminal?

Comment: I am not sure no. However if I remove the \r i get the following error Category Timestamp Duration Message Line Position
Error 7/27/2013 12:10:07 PM 0:00:00.070 <link> - MySQL Database Error: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED. 7 0

Comment: And how do you invoke the above command? From the commandline or from some external application?

Comment: external application Toad for MySQL

Comment: It has been a while, but you didn't escape your second \ .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this help but the problem seems to be related to your servers binary log format.
Try changing your binary log format in your `my.cnf` file to:

```
binlog_format=ROW
```

and restart your server, you could also try setting the `binlog_format` configuration to `MIXED`

You can also change the format only for the current session:

```
SET SESSION binlog_format = ROW;
TRUNCATE TABLE setup_new_campaign;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\Uploads\setup_new_campaign.csv'
INTO table setup_new_campaign
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The line-endings is probably terminated by `\n` and not `\r\n`

Comment: I tried to change the session binlog_format by using the secod set of code you posted. that give me the following error Category Timestamp Duration Message Line Position
Error 7/27/2013 12:36:23 PM 0:01:01.162 <link> - MySQL Database Error: Fatal error encountered during command execution. 8 0

Comment: @Mike - Have you have tried both type of line-endings ie `\n` and `\r\n`?

Comment: @Mike - You could also try to run the statements directly from the commandline using `mysql -u<username> -p<password> -e"<statements>" The above could works without problem for me.